# Parse.com trying to update user afterSave CloudCode

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to use an afterSave function to update a field called accountBallance on a User object after something has been saved/updated to my Transactions object:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Transactions", function(request) {
  var amount = request.object.get("amount");
  var userId = request.object.get("user").id;
  console.log("Amount: " + amount);
  console.log("User: " + userId);


  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
   var user = new Parse.User();
   var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
   query.equalTo("objectId", userId);
   query.first({
      success: function(myObject) {
         var newBallance =  myObject.get("accountBallance") + amount;

         myObject.set("accountBallance", newBallance);
         myObject.save();

         // Set the job's success status
        response.success("User: " + userID + " Balance was updated with: " + amount);

      },
      error: function() {
         // Set the job's success status
        response.error("Couldn't update transaction!");
      }
   });


});
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Result: TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
>       at query.first.success (main.js:22:38)
>       at Parse.js:2:5786
>       at r (Parse.js:2:4981)
>       at Parse.js:2:4531
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Object.w.each.w.forEach [as _arrayEach] (Parse.js:1:666)
>       at n.extend.resolve (Parse.js:2:4482)
>       at r (Parse.js:2:5117)
>       at Parse.js:2:4531
>       at Array.forEach (native)

Any advice/help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should check if request.object.get("user") is null or not. You probabely trying to access id field of null user object.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input, but it's not null.  In the begining when I do: var userId = request.object.get("user").id; and log: console.log("User: " + userId); I get a valid userId.  I've even tried replacing it with a valid objectId for a user explicitly.

Comment: I should probably say that the value of the user field is a pointer to the Parse _User table.

Comment: Did you try setting request.object.get("user") directky to userId variable? Try this if you didn't try yet. Additionally you can print request.object to console to see what is in and on worst case you can make another query to Transactions for getting the row and required data.

Comment: request.user.id works for me. please refer to http://www.parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Cloud.AfterSaveRequest.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the value returned from your query (myObject) is null.  You should add a check for this:

```
if(myObject){
    // We are good!
}else{
    // user not found...maybe it was deleted?
}
```

Are you absolutely sure that the objectId printed here

```
console.log("User: " + userId);
```

Is in your user table?